# The send transactions "from" field must be defined!

Tags: truffle, react

I am trying to call a function of a contract that has been deployed to Ganache. I am trying to call a function that makes payouts to a few addresses and can be called by owner only. When I am calling the function, I get this error:

```
 The send transactions "from" field must be defined!
```

I don't understand the problem. All this contract does is that it transfers the contract balance to a few addresses. It is not payable. So, how do I resolve this error?

Contract Function:

```
function distributePrizes() public _ownerOnly{
    uint numberWinner = generateNumber();
    address[100] memory winners; // We have to create a temporary in memory array with fixed size
      uint256 count = 0; // This is the count for the array of winners
      for(uint256 i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
         address playerAddress = players[i];
         if(playerInfo[playerAddress].numberSelected == numberWinner){
            winners[count] = playerAddress;
            count++;
         }
         delete playerInfo[playerAddress]; // Delete all the players
      }
      winnerArray = winners;
      players.length = 0; // Delete all the players array
      uint256 winnerEtherAmount = totalBet / winners.length; // How much each winner gets
      for(uint256 j = 0; j < count; j++){
         if(winners[j] != address(0)) // Check that the address in this fixed array is not empty
         winners[j].transfer(winnerEtherAmount);
      }

    }
```

React function where the contract function is being called:

```
selectWinner = async (e) =>{
    const { accounts, contract, web3 } = this.state;
    const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(contract.address);
    //console.log('Winners selected')
    await contract.distributePrizes();
    const newBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(contract.address);
    const winners = await contract.winnerArray;
    this.setState({winnerAddress: winners, totalBet: newBalance})
  }
```

Comment: How about sharing some code here?

Comment: I have shared some code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `accounts[0]` as your default account, modify this line:

`await contract.distributePrizes();`

to:

`await contract.distributePrizes({from: accounts[0]});`

Or when you are creating your `web3` object:

```
let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
web3.eth.defaultAccount = accounts[0]
```

Another option: if you have `geth` or `truffle` installed, open a console, for example doing:

`geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8545`
or 
`truffle console`

and then:

`eth.defaultAccount = eth.accounts[0]` (for `geth`)
or

```
let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
web3.eth.defaultAccount = accounts[0]
```

for `truffle`

If you want `accounts[0]` to be your default account, of course.

Note: `web3.eth.accounts` is deprecated. Use `web3.eth.getAccounts()` instead