# Truffle test {from} option is ignored

Tags: solidity, truffle

To test my contracts i need to use multiple accounts. I hoped that changing value of `from` option will help me with this. But it is ignored and msg.sender is always accounts[0] (my deployer)

Truffle

```
await this.proposal.increaseCredit(fromWei(11, 'micro'), {from: '0x4e66526f50b4c09d0eee8ee01294c7003cfed859'})
```

Solidity

```
function increaseCredit(uint _amount) public {
    emit Test(msg.sender, address(this));
}
```

Here is event log:

```
Test(_test1: 0xd3fe1c237a5dddd86d27b3c2ff00885629176765, _test2: 0xefbed05633cc5a9feafe6fc0836bded1f3763a62)
```

this is not a fallback/payable function. So sendTransaction here doesnt fit

What im doing wrong?

Comment: Try this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/62804/44907

Comment: As you see ive did the same for truffle. I tried to change `from` option param

Comment: Can you show the code for your Test event? Also try changing your default account as they explain in the post too.